Add custom serviceworker file in PWA Venia React frontend
In Magento PWA Venia [ React frontend ]  , by default there is file called sw.js in src/ServiceWorker/sw.js and we can load that file in  website.com
In the similar way, How to create customsw.js and load the file in
website.com/customsw.js ?
Update :
There is some code which is loading in website.com/sw.js . Like that only i want to add below code and i want to load only that below code when i hit the url : website.com [ abc.js is not yet created] .  I want to know where to create abc.js file in PWA React Venia setup.
var config = {
    apiKey: 'AyBkeG8-mwvw9OHmdDco',
    messagingSenderId: '526757012698',
    appId: '1:52698:web:0d6e71e3',
    projectId: 'project-9d6d6',
    user_key: 'xyz',
    siteid: 'defe'
};
importScripts('//smartech.com/swv4.js'); 


Hello @baby can you please explain me more

@RohitGohel please check the update section in question

i have check and r&d for that but I think sw.js file is right file to add the code

@RohitGohel but the client want that code in different path as they are telling multiple sessions will be created

imagin if I create the file and run your file URL in Chrome so you need this type of output? - https://prnt.sc/OOhfK1QbCZ3W

@RohitGohel exactly, I need that only


Create the custom service worker file: You can create a new file named sw.js in the src/ServiceWorker directory of your project.
Add the code into sw.js file

var config = {
   apiKey: 'AyBkeG8-mwvw9OHmdDco',
   messagingSenderId: '526757012698',
   appId: '1:52698:web:0d6e71e3',
   projectId: 'project-9d6d6',
   user_key: 'xyz',
   siteid: 'defe'
};
importScripts('//smartech.com/swv4.js');


Modify the service worker registration: n your src/ServiceWorker/index.js file, update the registration code to include your custom service worker file sw.js

// Register the service worker
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
   window.addEventListener('load', () => {
       navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js') 
           .then(registration => {
               console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
           })
           .catch(err => {
               console.error('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
           });
   });
}

Build your project and Deploy your changes.

We need to add the code in another file instead of sw,js, because we already have sw.js file, so is it possible to create another sw.js[ with different name like sw2.js ] file for our project ?

Yes anyfile name would be consider and you will need to change file name in   navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')  #here sw2.js

Here is our  src/registerSW.js :  https://pastebin.com/hwFUPzDe  . do i need to update in this file ?

I have updated your code here : src/registerSW.js : https://pastebin.com/YzTvUWJV , but i gave me error as 404 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat

There is no index.js file under src/ServiceWorker, the navigator related code is in registerSW.js , is it fine if i add your code there ? https://imgur.com/a/KNg4yWB

i am facing this link error

Do you have any idea why the file is not loading here
